# AWS DynamoDB insert values in a LIST or NUMBER SET

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS DynamoDB for iOS. I created a table with a column of NumberSet. Now I'm trying to add values on it using the app but wondering why it saves differently.

For example:
I added values on NumberSet manually on the browser and its values will look like `{123, 456, 789}`

While on using the app, it saves but it saves as `[{"N": 123}, {"N": 456}, {"N": 789}]` Any idea on how to save a NumberSet? I'm using swift on this.

Comment: can you share some code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I just found out that I need to use a NSSet/NSMutableset to store NumberSet.